# Flutter:I want to make my list scrollable in both horizontal and vertical directions

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Tree-shaped list and a regular list, but their children contain Expanded and I don't want to change them, and I also want to scroll them horizontally and vertically:

`

```
 Widget bodyTabletOrMobilePos({required BoxConstraints constraints}) => Container(
          width: constraints.maxWidth,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            border: Border.all(width: 0.3, color: Colors.grey.shade300),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                color: kBackgroundColor,
                child: search,
              ),
              Divider(
                height: 2,
                thickness: 0.5,
              ),
              //Header Row
              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: IntrinsicWidth(
                      child:  Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                            child: rowHeader,
                          ),
                          Divider(
                            height: 0,
                            thickness: 0.5,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                            child: Visibility(
                              //Shimmer Loading
                              visible: !isLoading,
                              replacement: LoadingSimmer(
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                    itemBuilder: (x, i) {
                                      return !i.isOdd
                                          ? Row(children: [
                                        Flexible(child: lod, flex: 10),
                                        SizedBox(width: 20),
                                        Flexible(child: lod, flex: 40),
                                        SizedBox(width: 20),
                                        Flexible(child: lod, flex: 30),
                                        SizedBox(width: 20),
                                        Flexible(child: lod, flex: 50),
                                        SizedBox(width: 20),
                                        Flexible(child: lod, flex: 5),
                                        SizedBox(width: 20),
                                        Flexible(child: lod, flex: 20),
                                      ])
                                          : SizedBox(
                                        height: 35,
                                      );
                                    },
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    itemCount: 18),
                              ),
                              child: Visibility(
                                //check for data
                                visible: data.isNotEmpty,
                                replacement: Container(
                                    width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width,
                                    height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height / 2,
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: Empty(
                                      iconSized:
                                      Responsive.isDesktop(context) ? 70 : null,
                                      msg: 'لا يوجد بيانات',
                                    )),
                                child: Visibility(
                                  visible: !isTree,
                                  //for tree
                                  replacement: TreeViewEntity(
                                      data: data,
                                      width: double.maxFinite,
                                      customWidget: (item) => Container(
                                        padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: data.indexOf(item).isOdd
                                              ? Colors.grey.withAlpha(30)
                                              : null,
                                        ),
                                        child: Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Expanded(
                                              child: row(item, data.indexOf(item)),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      onTap: onTap,
                                      config: config),
                                  //for not tree
                                  child: ListView.separated(
                                    // padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                      itemBuilder: (x, i) {
                                        var item = data[i];
                                        return InkWell(
                                          onTap: () {},
                                          child: AnimationList(
                                            position: i + 2,
                                            milliseconds: 50,
                                            child: Container(
                                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                                              padding:
                                              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: i.isOdd
                                                    ? Colors.grey.withAlpha(30)
                                                    : null,
                                              ),
                                              child: Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                children: [
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: row(item, i),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      },
                                      separatorBuilder: (x, i) => Divider(
                                        thickness: 0.3,
                                        height: 0,
                                      ),
                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                      itemCount: data.length),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),            ],
          ),
        );
```

`and i used layoutBuilder to get the constraint,,and i want the my list to take remaining size of my device

the row and rowHeader Widget is like this:

`

```
Padding(padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(bottom: Responsive.isMobile(context) ? 10 : 0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text(item.getName,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text(item.level?.toString() ?? '',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                                item.type == 0 ? 'ميزانية عمومية' : 'ارباح وخسائر',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                                p.accountTypes.firstWhere(
                                            (e) => e.id == item.accountTypeId,
                                            orElse: () => AccountType())
                                        .title ??
                                    '',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                                Instance.targets.firstWhere(
                                        (e) => e.id == item.targetId,
                                            orElse: () => Target())
                                        .title ??
                                    '',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                                Instance.branches.firstWhere(
                                        (e) => e.id == item.branchId,
                                            orElse: () => Branch())
                                        .title ??
                                    '',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                              child: Checkbox(
                                  value: item.status??false,
                                  onChanged: (x) async {
                                    print(' item.status ${item.status}');
                                    await p.changeStatus(widget.code, context, item);
                                    item.status=!(item.status!);
                                    p.refresh();
                                    print(' item.status ${item.status}');

                                  })),
                          Expanded(
                              child: Responsive.isDesktop(context) ?
                              Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  if(isEdit(widget.code))
                                  transactionEntity( onTap:() =>p.edit(context, item), icon: Icons.edit),
                                  SizedBox(width: 5,),
                                  if( isDelete(widget.code))
                                    transactionEntity( onTap:() =>p.delete(context, item), icon: Icons.delete),
                                ],
                              ):
                              buildPopupMenuActions([
                                if(isEdit(widget.code))
                                  buildPopupMenuItem(
                                      title:
                                      'تعديل',
                                      iconData:
                                      Icons.edit,
                                      onClick: () => p.edit(context, item),
                                      context: context),
                                if( isDelete(widget.code))
                                  buildPopupMenuItem(
                                      title:
                                      'حذف',
                                      iconData:
                                      CupertinoIcons.delete,
                                      onClick: () => p.delete(context, item),
                                      context: context),
                              ]),

                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),`

I want to make this section:            Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                    child: rowHeader,
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    height: 0,
                    thickness: 0.5,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                    child: Visibility(
                      //Shimmer Loading
                      visible: !isLoading,
                      replacement: LoadingSimmer(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                            itemBuilder: (x, i) {
                              return !i.isOdd
                                  ? Row(children: [
                                      Flexible(child: lod, flex: 10),
                                      SizedBox(width: 20),
                                      Flexible(child: lod, flex: 40),
                                      SizedBox(width: 20),
                                      Flexible(child: lod, flex: 30),
                                      SizedBox(width: 20),
                                      Flexible(child: lod, flex: 50),
                                      SizedBox(width: 20),
                                      Flexible(child: lod, flex: 5),
                                      SizedBox(width: 20),
                                      Flexible(child: lod, flex: 20),
                                    ])
                                  : SizedBox(
                                      height: 35,
                                    );
                            },
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: 18),
                      ),
                      child: Visibility(
                        //check for data
                        visible: data.isNotEmpty,
                        replacement: Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width,
                            height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height / 2,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Empty(
                              iconSized:
                                  Responsive.isDesktop(context) ? 70 : null,
                              msg: 'لا يوجد بيانات',
                            )),
                        child: Visibility(
                          visible: !isTree,
                          //for tree
                          replacement: TreeViewEntity(
                              data: data,
                              width: double.maxFinite,
                              customWidget: (item) => Container(
                                    padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: data.indexOf(item).isOdd
                                          ? Colors.grey.withAlpha(30)
                                          : null,
                                    ),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: row(item, data.indexOf(item)),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                              onTap: onTap,
                              config: config),
                          //for not tree
                          child: ListView.separated(
                              // padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                              itemBuilder: (x, i) {
                                var item = data[i];
                                return InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  child: AnimationList(
                                    position: i + 2,
                                    milliseconds: 50,
                                    child: Container(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: i.isOdd
                                            ? Colors.grey.withAlpha(30)
                                            : null,
                                      ),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: row(item, i),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              separatorBuilder: (x, i) => Divider(
                                    thickness: 0.3,
                                    height: 0,
                                  ),
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemCount: data.length),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )),
```

---

responsive in any screen size,but i face this error:

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library ============================================
The following assertion was thrown during paint():
Assertion failed: file:///D:/sdk/asma/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:544:12
child.hasSize
is not true

The relevant error-causing widget was:  and some time i faced this error:

RenderBox was not laid out,,can you help me to fix this error??
```

Comment: @Ildeberto Vasconcelos thanx alot

Answer (score 0):

Right on time! I had a task where I needed to do a TableView like looking calendar for a client. I used multiple ListView's and [Linked scroll controllers](https://github.com/google/flutter.widgets/tree/master/packages/linked_scroll_controller) back then to achieve this, but now you have [two_dimensional_scrollables](https://pub.dev/packages/two_dimensional_scrollables) right from Flutter.
And some example [here](https://karthikponnam.medium.com/two-dimensional-scrollables-flutter-4c04852f7dbf) too.

Comment: I tried that!,,but my prob;lem is i have expanded in my rowHeader and row,,and i cant give him fixed size ,, becuase i want my list to take the space od any devices!

Comment: Then your best bet would be to take the device width divide it into the number of rows you want to have and that's your row width. Create that many rows and continue from there.